# What is var/package really for?

Tags: package

Maybe I am completely missing something, but I have yet to find a clear explanation of exactly what the var/package directory is, and how it is used. I've seen it included in a lot of problem solutions (clear it, check for xyz file there, etc) but what is it actually *for*, specifically?

Comment: This directory contains the xml files of the installed extensions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`var/package` is where all the installed packages are (not the actual content of the package but the information of what the package is).
It is used by the Magento Connect Manager, if we open one of the files in there we find this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
    <name>Lib_Google_Checkout</name>
    <version>1.5.0.0</version>
    <stability>stable</stability>
    <license>Apache License</license>
    <channel>community</channel>
    <extends/>
    <summary>Google Checkout Library</summary>
    <description>Google Checkout Library</description>
    <notes>1.5.0.0</notes>
    <authors><author><name>Magento Core Team</name><user>core</user><email>core@magentocommerce.com</email></author></authors>
    <date>2011-02-08</date>
    <time>16:02:18</time>
    <contents><target name="magelib"><dir name="googlecheckout"><file name="googlecart.php" hash="5b11319b8489cd2cb50bf2f38797fbb0"/><file name="googleitem.php" hash="2305b454c0b524f835e489a224070c1b"/><file name="googlelog.php" hash="402dfa7bf30450451d6dd76db20e8996"/><file name="googlemerchantcalculations.php" hash="2b8ca5d31c7dfc5f1b305ad0f0f8dc8d"/><file name="googlerequest.php" hash="2d9f2ffdb96c38f57772c151f517fe4c"/><file name="googleresponse.php" hash="4af0da6d2d9f461e9e072a81512a205e"/><file name="googleresult.php" hash="9643ea49bfeb16224f43a8ea79571094"/><file name="googleshipping.php" hash="ba2aa1ce3d1375b48a214fba19f589ff"/><file name="googletax.php" hash="55b8cd73340e491a47f62f8b887404ed"/><dir name="xml-processing"><file name="gc_xmlbuilder.php" hash="8b008a09d4ff42408fb601980f965dac"/><file name="gc_xmlparser.php" hash="9845e8a617eef46f0209140c9f26a90b"/></dir></dir></target></contents>
    <compatible/>
    <dependencies><required><php><min>5.2.0</min><max>6.0.0</max></php></required></dependencies>
</package>
```

As you can see the name, version, content, license, dependencies, etc. are listed in here.
This only applies to packages installed through the Magento Connect Manager.

Comment: And you are free to delete this after the package has been installed

Comment: @brentwpeterson did you figure out if these could be deleted?