# I deleted /var/package by accident, what are the consequences?

Tags: package

As the title says, I accidentally deleted `/var/package/`.

What kind of issues can this cause, is it possible to recover or rebuild the tree, and if so, how?

Comment: But, is it possible to recover all the xml package that were in the directory?

If so, how?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate!

Comment: WaPoNe, please edit the question and add this part about recovering.

Comment: WaPo, important distinction for a moment: Is this a hypothetical question about what might happen *if* you delete that directory, or are you asking for help because you *did* accidentally delete it and now aren't sure what might or might not break?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: I added that part in my question.

Comment: @Shadur: I'm asking for help because you did accidentally delete it and now am not sure what might or might not break

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't use magento connect, it doesn't matter, if you do, magento maybe forgets what is installed and which files are part of the package

Comment: upvote for you fabian

Comment: And since Magento Connect is a horribly problematic piece of work, I only do manual installs, so I'd never miss it at all. And the package management often doesn't function well for the third party modules that would be my only interest in using Magento Connect given the full Magento upgrade failures where Connect has only partially updated stuff have put me off it indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

It contains information about extensions that are installed in your system. It is normally using by Magento Connect. You can delete all contents without any fear, **if all extensions are working perfectly.**

For more details, have a look on this **[thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/what-is-var-package-really-for)**

Comment: And that's a mighty big 'if' indeed.

Answer (score 0):

i guess `it may be creating issue when you want to upgrade  your magento  system to upper version`

or `if want to update an module package then it create issue`.

During time `of upgradation it check package from here`

Comment: only if you used magento connect, does it?

Comment: it  must creating issue if  magento is upgrading using  connect manager.it may effect on other upgradation process.i am not sure about  100%

Comment: Only issue is that it will be recreated if your third party module install has information to put in it, otherwise, no. Haven't seen a module installer that consults it before running the upgrade scripts.