# Is it safe to delete old magento version files?

Tags: magento-1.9

In my magento root folder under var/package/ I can see all the xml files for all the magento versions I've ever had. Here's an example of what I'm seeing.

```
Cm_RedisSession-1.8.0.0.xml 1.17 KB 0755
Cm_RedisSession-1.9.2.0.xml 1.17 KB 0644
Cm_RedisSession-1.9.2.1.xml 1.17 KB 0644
Cm_RedisSession-1.9.2.2.xml 1.17 KB 0644
```

Is it safe to delete these files up to my current version 1.9.2.2?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove these files. It will not create any issue in your setup. for more information about this folder and files you can check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/what-is-var-package-really-for).